# Referencing other web project overriding current authentication ASP.NET mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I have a project A which is web project with "windows authentication" in web.config file , and I have a Project B with "form authentication" .

So I needed to use some classes in project A from project B so I Added project B as a reference in Project A .

I had an issue after that , I noticed project A "Authorize" acts like project B authentication "Form" , while project A is configured to use Windows authentication .

So what should I do to use Project B code, without project B authentication ?

I made sure that in web config I have forms authentication in project A

Comment: Why not rather pull the common code out into another project so you don’t have one web project referencing another?

Comment: well , it seems this is the right thing , but wondering if issue here is normal

Comment: The "normal" thing to do is to figure out which parts of your code are _"agnostic"_ to _"any"_ project depending on it. Obviously, conflicting authentication schemes wouldn't be "agnostic".